# Using QR decomposition to solve a system of equations with a singular matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is singular and $x,b\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are such that $Ax=b$, am I right in thinking that the upper triangular matrix $R$ of $A$'s $QR$ decomposition must have at least one diagonal entry because otherwise saying $Rx=Q^{T}b$ and using backward substitution would give one definite answer for $x$. But, because $A$ is singular, there cannot be just one solution to the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your matrix $A$ is singular, then you can use the pivoted QR factorisation:
$$
A\Pi=QR,
$$
where $\Pi$ is a permutation matrix, $Q$ is square orthogonal and the triangular $R$ has the block form
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $R_{11}\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ ($r$ is the rank of $A$) is nonsingular and upper triangular.
Then $Ax=b$ is equivalent to
$$
R\tilde{x}=\tilde{b}, \qquad \tilde{x}=\Pi^Tx, \quad \tilde{b}=Q^Tb.
$$
Using the partitioning $\tilde{x}=[\tilde{x}_1^T,\tilde{x}_2^T]^T$ and $\tilde{b}=[\tilde{b}_1^T,\tilde{b}_2^T]^T$ leads to
$$
R_{11}\tilde{x}_1+R_{12}\tilde{x}_2=\tilde{b}_1, \quad 0 = \tilde{b}_2.
$$
So, the system is solvable iff $\tilde{b}_2=0$ and any solution $x$ can be obtained by choosing an arbitrary vector $\tilde{x}_2$, solving $R_{11}\tilde{x}_1=\tilde{b}_1-R_{12}\tilde{x}_2$, and performing the permutation $x=\Pi\tilde{x}$. You might want to obtain, e.g., the minimum 2-norm solution, which can be done simply by choosing $\tilde{x}_2=0$.

Note that the QR decomposition can be less numerically reliable for solving rank-deficient problems than the SVD, or, more precisely, the [truncated SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Truncated_SVD) approach.